# BdMO 2016 National Secondary Problem 3.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles, angle

> $\triangle{ABC}$ is isosceles with $AB=AC$, $P$ is a point inside $\triangle {ABC}$ such that $\angle{BCP} = 30^{o}$, $\angle{APB} = 150 ^{o}$, $\angle{CAP}=39^{o}$. Find $\angle{BAP}$
>   [image]

This problem is from BdMO 2016 Nationals ( Secondary ), worth of $20$ points. I've tried it after the contest many many times. But couldn't find any solution. Any Hint/Full Solution will be helpful.

Comment: i have found an equation for the unknown angle $x$ which containes trigonometric functions

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner But in MO we are not supposed to use calculator. But if all the functions cancel out in the end then it is possible to use trigonometric functions.

Comment: i have note used any calculators

Comment: Is the equation solvable without using calculator? !

Comment: i will try it to solve the equation

Comment: Give the equation.. By knowing the solution is might be easy to solve the problem in hand

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Did you use Ceva's Trig Identity? That won't work because the final answer will be 13 degrees...

Comment: no i only used the theorem of sines

Comment: @XTL Would you mind posting the answer? How you got ans 13?

Comment: I drew it on geogebra...=( I tried to angle chase but it got no where.

Comment: @XTL I found this - 
Set $\angle BAP$ = anything $\leq 30$. This will lead to a valid combination of angles. But suppose $\angle {BAP} = 15$. Then we must assume that $BP=AP$. So for any other angle. So, there must be a proved solution, which can directly be found. :(    
So, we cant say that ans = 13 without any prove. Setting anything can lead to a valid triangle

Comment: @RezwanArefin If you actually construct that triangle, you will eventually lead to a contradiction. Using geogebra, I can prove that 13 is the unique answer. (This can be a good/fun exercise for you to see why) I'm still trying to find an olympiad style solution. I double I will be able to solve this as geometry is my weakest area. =/ I suspect this problem will require some clever handling like adding a line somewhere or rotating one of the triangles.

Comment: Who will let me use Geogebra in Olympiad ! :P However this was the 3rd problem of the Olympiad. This might not the that hard. :'(

Comment: @RezwanArefin Geogebra construction wasn't even that easy. =/ In Olympiad coaching, there is a saying "You might not be able to solve the number theory, or functional equations or game theory but you better solve the geometry problem!"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $Q$ be the point such that $\triangle{PQB}$ is equilateral and $C$ and $Q$ are on the same side of $PB$. Then $Q$ is the center of $\odot BPC$ and so $AQ$ is the perpendicular bisector of $BC$. Finally, as $\angle{APB} = 150^{\circ}$ we have $AP \perp QB$ and so $AP$ bisects $\angle{QAB}$. So $4\angle{BAP} = \angle{BAC}$ which implies that $3\angle{BAP} = \angle{CAP}$ which implies that $\angle{BAP} = 13^{\circ}$.

[image]

Comment: AND WE HAVE A WINNER! How did you figure out that you needed to construct $Q$?

Comment: added illustration

Comment: Could you explain a bit more why $Q$ is the center of $\odot BPC$?

Comment: @yurnero angle (60) at the centre of the circle is half the angle at the circumference (30, at $\angle BCP$), and $Q$ lies on the bisector of $BP$

Answer (score 3):

Angle-chasing with notations found on the figure below gives all angles as functions of a unique unknown angle $s$, as follows

[image]
$$\left\{\begin{aligned}t&=&141-s\\u&=&210-s\\z&=&s-40\\y&=&231-2s \end{aligned}\right.\tag{1}$$

and

$$x=2s-210\tag{2}$$

Remarks: 1) the last equation in (1) takes into account the fact that angle in $B$ = angle in $C$.
2) In this last expression, as the considered angle is acute, we must have $0 \leq 231-2s<90 \ \iff \ $

$$70.5 < s <115.5\tag{3}$$

It remains to find $s$. Thus, we have to find another relationship that could be called a *contiguity constraint* for triangles $ABP$ and $APC$ ; this constraint will come from the law of sines in each triangle :

$$\dfrac{a}{\sin(231-2v)}=\dfrac{b}{\sin(150)} \ \ \text{and} \ \ \dfrac{a}{\sin(141-s)}=\dfrac{b}{\sin(s)}\tag{4}$$

Expressing ratio $a/b$ in two ways and taking into account the value $\sin 150 =\tfrac12$, we get :

$$\underbrace{\sin(141-s)-2\sin(s)\sin(231-2s)}_{= \ \sin(3s+39)}=0 \tag{4}$$

(We don't enter here into computational details)

(4) is possible iff

$$3s+39=0 \ \text{mod.} \ 180 \tag{5}$$

which, taking into account the range given by (3) enforces $3s+39=360 \ \iff s=107$. Plugging this value into (2) gives

> $$x=13°$$